# The sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a probability question and I want to find the precise summation of:

$$\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{n^{p-1} - \sum_{x=0}^{p-2} n^x}{n^p}$$

Where $n$ is an integer greater than $1$. More precisely, I am wondering how variations of $n$ may affect the infinite sum (given this series is not diverging, for I think it converges).

As you may have guessed, I have failed so far.

Comment: What exactly would you like to know? Where does this come from? There might be an alternative approach to find your answer...

Comment: The case $n=2$ is OK, larger integers are not.

Comment: The series diverges except when $n=2$ (and then it sums to $1$).

Comment: oh, for n=2, that was obvious :P Thanks! Btw, does it diverge for  a greater n due to the increasing discrepancy between n^(p-1) and n^(p-2) as p approaches infinity? @ vonbrand, there isn't any concrete problem I got this from, there were some loosely related ones and I got inspired from them to create this, in retrospect rather boring series.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, why does it diverge for $n > 2$? Probably something silly I'm overlooking... and I'd ask you to make your comment into a complete answer, so this doesn't stay open.

Comment: Not boring, as it interested at least four people here ;-)

Comment: @vonbrand: One can compute the sum of the "inside" series. Then it is an easy calculation. But informally the inside series is about $\frac{1}{n-1}n^{p-1}$. If $n\gt 2$, that makes the $\sum_{p=1}^\infty$ a sum of terms bigger than a positive constant.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, see, it *was* a silly thing. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Not silly, unless you want to call most of the things we try silly.

Answer (score 0):

Your series equals to

$$\sum_{p = 1}^{\infty} \frac {(n - 2) n^{p - 1} + 1} {n^p (n - 1)} \sim \sum_{p = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n}$$

which diverges.